# Copying data from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a number of files that are broken up by steps in a folder. For example:
1.xlsx
2.xlsx
3.xlsx
(etc. to about 9 files)

Each of these files contain cells or graphs to copy to a monthly PowerPoint presentation that's already formatted and ready, just needs the data and would like to avoid using links.

I'm stuck at pasting data into the open file.

```vb
Sub summary()
    Dim pindex As Long
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pprsn As PowerPoint.Presentations
    Dim ppslide As PowerPoint.Slide

'Whats the date of folder?
folder = InputBox("Please enter date")

directory = "" + folder

'Define the path for the summary PPTX
pptfile = directory + "\summary.pptx"

'Define the steps in Excel WB's
sn = directory + "\1.xlsx"
pu = directory + "\2a.xlsx"
pe = directory + "\2b.xlsx"
in = directory + "\3"

'****1*****
    Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    ppt.Presentations.Open (pptfile)
    Workbooks.Open (sn)
    
    'Copy cells from sn
    Worksheets("Snapshot").Range("A1:L29").Copy
    
    'Paste into first slide in active pwerpoint presentation
???

End Sub
```

I tried different guides here and other websites. Most are creating a new PPT instead of editing one in the folder.
Any time I try to identify the indexID or use any other method it errors.
I'd like to work down the list copying each of the necessary cells & graphs into the PowerPoint presentation to help the team from having to rebuild their linked variables each month.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. I should have been pasting directly with shapes vs. trying to select a slide index. Secondly, my dim statement for pprsn had an S which changed the arguments it could handle slightly.